# GNU parallel read from several files

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, vcf-variant-call-format

I am trying to use GNU parallel to convert individual files with a bioinformatic tool called vcf2maf.

My command looks something like this:

```
${parallel} --link "perl ${vcf2maf} --input-vcf ${1} \
                                    --output-maf ${maf_dir}/${2}.maf \
                                    --tumor-id ${3} \
                                    --tmp-dir ${vcf_dir} \
                                    --vep-path ${vep_script} \
                                    --vep-data ${vep_data} \
                                    --ref-fasta ${fasta} \
                                    --filter-vcf ${filter_vcf}" :::: ${VCF_files} ${results} ${tumor_ids}
```

`VCF_files`, `results` and `tumor_ids` contain one entry per line and correspond to one another.

When I try and run the command I get the following error for every file:

`ERROR: Both input-vcf and output-maf must be defined!`

This confused me, because if I run the command manually, the program works as intended, so I dont think that the input/outpit paths are wrong. To confirm this, I also ran

`${parallel} --link "cat ${1}" :::: ${VCF_files} ${results} ${tumor_ids}`,
which correctly prints the contents of the VCF files, whose path is listed in `VCF_files`.

I am really confused what I did wrong, if anyone could help me out, I'd be very thankful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a command this long I would normally define a function:

```
doit() {
  ...
}
export -f doit
```

Then test this on a single input.

When it works:

```
parallel --link doit :::: ${VCF_files} ${results} ${tumor_ids}
```

But if you want to use a single command it will look something like:

```
${parallel} --link "perl ${vcf2maf} --input-vcf {1} \
                                --output-maf ${maf_dir}/{2}.maf \
                                --tumor-id {3} \
                                --tmp-dir ${vcf_dir} \
                                --vep-path ${vep_script} \
                                --vep-data ${vep_data} \
                                --ref-fasta ${fasta} \
                                --filter-vcf ${filter_vcf}" :::: ${VCF_files} ${results} ${tumor_ids}
```

GNU Parallel's replacement strings are {1}, {2}, and {3} - not  ${1}, ${2}, and ${3}.

`--dryrun` is your friend when GNU Parallel does not do what you expect it to do.